# Linux mint 13 - Update to mint 17 faillure

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, grub

I've tryed to update my system (linux mint 13 to linux mint 17) using this procedure (https://www.linuxtricks.fr/wiki/mettre-a-niveau-linux-mint-vers-une-nouvelle-version) and doesn't work. 
Now I only have acces to windows 7 (once the system is on dual boot) but the GRUB shows the lines with LINUX MINT 13 3.13.0.110 - generic (/dev/sd5)
If i click on this option i see a small window to put my login and password and then i have the message saying that "cinnamon, not present".
Anyone have an idea how can i repair it? Thank you for yours answers.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, but you may try to boot from a live USB then do:

- either boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
- or grub-install http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Best of luck

Comment: He can boot, he can't access his DE, apparently.